# What is the domain and the range of the function given below?

Tags: functions

The plot of function & the function definition is here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/p4y97ww37l

**Edit**
In case the above link isn't working,here's the function definition:

$$y=\left \lceil x \right \rceil.sin\frac{\pi}{\left \lceil x+1 \right \rceil}$$

Spikes are also observed at x=(2^n)-1 where n=1,2,3...

Can anyone provide any explanation for the observed peaks?

Also what would be the Domain & Range of this function?
Please also provide a method for finding it without plotting it.

Comment: Cool...it seems to converge to $\pi$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Same is the case for x $\rightarrow -\infty$

Comment: The page doesn't load for me.  Could you edit your post to include the definition?

Comment: Here's the function:

$$y=\left \lceil x \right \rceil.sin\frac{\pi}{\left \lceil x+1 \right \rceil}$$

Comment: The spikes are an artifact of the plotting system, and are not "real". Observe that the expressions $\lceil x \rceil$ and $\lceil x + 1 \rceil$ have identical step discontinuities.  Examining the continuous version $x \sin \frac {\pi}{x + 1}$ shows what happens when $x$ is large, and the behaviour near but outside the interval $(-2, -1]$ is dependent upon a few fixed values. The value when $x \in (-2, -1]$ is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, the only reason the function would be undefined would be a division by zero, i.e. as long as $x$ is not in $[-1,0)$, the function is defined.
Thus, the domain is 
$$\{x:x<-1 \text{ or } x\geq 0\}.$$

Now, the function is constant on any interval of the form $[n,n+1)$, where $n\in\mathbb Z$ (although, again undefined when $n=-1$).  Thus, one way to write the range is as

$$\{n\sin(\pi/(n+1)): n\in\mathbb Z \setminus \{-1\}\}.$$

I don't know that there is any easier way to describe the set, although we can certainly see some of it's characteristics.  Using the fact that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1,$$
it's not too hard to see that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \pm\infty} n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right) = \pi.$$
Thus, $\pi$ is a cluster point of the range, while all other points are isolated. Beyond that, I think a graph is a reasonable thing to have.  In the following picture, we see the graph together with a portion of the range plotted as red dots on the $y$-axis.

[image]